# how to change function name of a anchor tag with a span using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<span class="action_bar" 
      id="dupquickaddchildassetbutton'+'_'+nodeid+'_'+'-1'+'"
      style="background-color: rgb(226, 225, 225);
             font-size: 10pt;
             font-weight: 700;
             visibility: hidden;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editchildassetquickmode('+nodeid+',1,-1);">
        <img src="/images/chain-symbol-add.jpg" title="Quick connect child node" border="0" width="16">
    </a>
</span>
```

now I want to change the parameter in this function -1 to actual group id.
so, how do I select that anchor tag and change that value in parameter?

Comment: Using inline CSS and JS on elements... You should REALLY reconsider that piece of code.. Where is the groupid located?

Answer (score 0):

Just use JQuery to create an instance of your anchor tag and override onclick function

```
//select span, and all a inside the span and bind the click event with actual parameter
    $("#dupquickaddchildassetbutton a").onclick(editchildassetquickmode('+nodeid+',1,actualGroupId));
```

Comment: I have tried this way:var quick_asset_selector_div = $("span[id^='dupquickaddchildassetbutton']");
    var quick_asset_link_selector = $(quick_asset_selector_div).children("a");
    var def_func_name = $(quick_asset_link_selector).attr('onclick'));but I am not able to replace the parameter in that function

Comment: :- In this case why you use '+nodeid+' in your example..I didn't get it